# My jQuery each function is displaying an extra row as undefined

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, json

I am displaying json data into html div using `$.getJSON` and each function . my alert is displaying right data but after posting it to html home page it is displaying an extra div as undefined value.

here is my screen shots and code

[image: alert]

[image: html div]

```
$.getJSON(url,function(data) {

                            if(data){
                                alert("hey got the data"+JSON.stringify(data));
                                 var arr = data.length;

                                 //for(var i=0 ;i<arr; i++){

                                   $.each(data, function(i,element) {
                                        $("#postjson").append(  
                                            '<div id="'+element.id+'">'
                                            +'<p>'
                                            +'FirstName:'+element.FirstName+'<br/>'

                                            +'MiddleName:'+element.MiddleName+'<br/>'
                                            +'LastName:'+element.LastName+'<br/>'
                                            +'Gender:'+element.Gender+'<br/>'
                                            +'Location:'+element.Location+'<br/>'
                                            +'Email:'+element.Email+'<br/>'
                                            +'Mobile:'+element.Mobile+'<br/>'
                                            +'</p>'
                                            +'</div>'
                                        );
                                    });
                                   }
                            else {
                                return;             
                            }

                        // once we've loaded
                        // kill the loading stuff
                        ListingCountPage++;
                        loading = false;
                        $(".loading").remove();

                        });
                    }


            $(function() {
            loadData();
        $(window).scroll(function(){

                if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
                    // add the loading box
                    if(loading == false){
                        loading = true;
                        $("#postjson").append("<div class='loading'>Loading...</div>");
                        loadData();
                    }

                }
        }); 


      });
            </script>

            <div class="grid" id="postjson">
            </div>
```

How is this caused and how can I fix it?

Comment: can provide sample output

Comment: wrong closing maybe caused your code is closing like this `$(".loading").remove();  });  }` it should be `$(".loading").remove();} });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the data shown in image there is two elements in the array. While iterating using `$.each()` the second iteration takes the second element, which doesn't have those properties defined, so it will append second div values as undefined.

---

If you just want to append the first element from the arraythen no need to use `$.each()` here, just get the first element and based on that object.

```
var element = data[0];

$("#postjson").append(
  '<div id="' + element.id + '">' + '<p>' + 'FirstName:' + element.FirstName + '<br/>' + 'MiddleName:' + element.MiddleName + '<br/>' + 'LastName:' + element.LastName + '<br/>' + 'Gender:' + element.Gender + '<br/>' + 'Location:' + element.Location + '<br/>' + 'Email:' + element.Email + '<br/>' + 'Mobile:' + element.Mobile + '<br/>' + '</p>' + '</div>'
);
```

---

Or in case you want to append multiple element from array then add an if condition to check that those properties are defined.

Comment: @Cooolranjan : glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

the data variable contains two objects instead of one as i guess you think. the BookTitle, BookGenre, BookWriter and BookDescription are another object in which FirstName, LastName etc. are undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the Json meaning full with two variables as personalDetails and bookDetails so that you can iterate only personal details like

```
$.each(data.personalDetails, function(i,element) {
  // your code here related to personal details
});
```